# How to use Kedro with Great-expectations?

Tags: python, airflow, kedro, great-expectations

I am using Kedro to create a pipeline for ETL purposes and column specific validations are being done using Great-Expectations. There is a `hooks.py` file listed in Kedro documentation [here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks/examples.html#add-data-validation). This hook is registered as per the instructions mentioned on Kedro-docs.

This is my current workflow:
The workflow:

1. Created a kedro project using `kedro new`, project name `ecom_analytics`
2. Stored the datasets in `data/01_raw` folder called `dataset_raw.csv` & `dataset_validate.csv`
3. Initialize great_expectations project using `great_expectations init`
4. Create a new datasource using `great_expectations datasource new`. The name I added was `main_datasource`
5. Create a new expectation using `great_expectations suite new`. This expectation is called data.raw using data assistant
6. Edited the great_expectations suite using `great_expectations suite edit data.raw`
7. Created the catalog entries for the datasets in `data/01_raw`
8. Added the Great expectations `hooks.py' given in the kedro documentation and registered the hook on` settings.py` file
9. Tried `kedro viz --autoreload`. This works to view the visualisation
10. When using `kedro run` it gives the error

```
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/data_context/abstract_dat │
│ a_context.py:758 in get_batch                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│    755 │   │   else:                                                                             │
│    756 │   │   │   data_asset_type = arg3                                                        │
│    757 │   │   batch_parameters = kwargs.get("batch_parameters")                                 │
│ ❱  758 │   │   return self._get_batch_v2(                                                        │
│    759 │   │   │   batch_kwargs=batch_kwargs,                                                    │
│    760 │   │   │   expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name,                                │
│    761 │   │   │   data_asset_type=data_asset_type,                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/great_expectations/data_context/data_context/abstract_dat │
│ a_context.py:867 in _get_batch_v2                                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│    864 │   │   │   expectation_suite = self.get_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name)        │
│    865 │   │                                                                                     │
│    866 │   │   datasource = self.get_datasource(batch_kwargs.get("datasource"))  # type: ignore  │
│ ❱  867 │   │   batch = datasource.get_batch(  # type: ignore[union-attr]                         │
│    868 │   │   │   batch_kwargs=batch_kwargs, batch_parameters=batch_parameters                  │
│    869 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│    870 │   │   if data_asset_type is None:                                                       │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AttributeError: 'Datasource' object has no attribute 'get_batch'
```

Please use the latest develop branch for the following project to look through the issue : https://github.com/DhavalThkkar/ecom-analytics

This is extremely difficult to work with. I have loaded the dataset for which I want to check validations inside the `data/01_raw` folder. If someone can help me with an end-2-end example for this repo, it'd really be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can check a minimal example here: https://github.com/erwinpaillacan/kedro-great-expectations-example

Basically, you need to define:

- A memory dataset, which is already defined in the example
- Define your expectations
- Define your checkpoint linked to your expectation.
- A mapper dataset: checkpoint conf/base/parameters/great_expectations_hook.yml

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the datasource. For more information (and example code to resolve a very similar issue), see https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/1389#issuecomment-624955813.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. I have updated the description with the exact workflow which I have used again to land at the same issue again